# Expectation values for products of sums

Tags: probability, expected-value

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables with means $\mu_x$, $\mu_y$ and variance $\sigma_x^2$, $\sigma_y^2$.

One can show that (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squared_deviations_from_the_mean)),
\begin{equation}
E\left(\left(\sum X\right)^2\right) = N\sigma_x^2 + N^2\mu_x^2
.
\end{equation}

Let's now consider the product
\begin{equation}
E\left(\left(\sum X\right)\cdot \left(\sum Y\right)\right).
\end{equation}
Here we assume that both sums are over $N$ random variables. The result I obtained for this product is
\begin{equation}
E\left(\left(\sum X\right)\cdot \left(\sum Y\right)\right)
\overset{?}{=}
N^2\mu_x\mu_y
.
\end{equation}
Numerical work seems to indicate that this is correct, however if I set $Y = X$, the previously mentioned result is not recovered.

Any help or resources would be appreciated!

Comment: The second result rests on independence. But if you set $Y=X$ then there is no independence.

Comment: Oh yes, or course! Now, what if $Y$ is a function of $X$ say $X^2$? Thanks!

Comment: If $Y = X^2$ then you need to know the distribution of $X$ to find the correlation between $X$ and $Y$, and in some cases it will not be an easy calculation.  But if $X$ is symmetrically distributed about $0$ then the correlation is $0$ as is $\mu_x$, so the calculation would give $0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $N^2\mu_x\mu_y$ result comes from independence, implying correlation of $\rho=0$.

But  if $Y=X$ there is no independence but instead correlation of $\rho=1$

More generally, if $X$ and $Y$ have correlation of $\rho$ (you will have $-1 \le \rho \le 1$), then $$\mathbb E\left(\sum\limits_1^{N_x} X\cdot \sum\limits_1^{N_y} Y\right) = \rho \sqrt{N_x N_y  \sigma_x^2 \sigma_y^2} + N_x N_y \mu_x\mu_y$$

and you can derive both your results from this