# Expectation values for products of sums of correlated variables

Tags: probability, expected-value

Suppose we have three independent random variables $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ with known means and variances. Let $W\equiv X\cdot Z$ and $V = Y\cdot Z$. I am attempting to find the average,
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}
\left[
\left(
\sum W
\right)
\left(
\sum V
\right)
\right]
.
\end{equation}

From a previous [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3850094/expectation-values-for-products-of-sums), I know that this is given by

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}
\left[
\left(
\sum_{1}^{N_W} W
\right)
\left(
\sum_{1}^{N_V} V
\right)
\right]
=
\rho_{WV}\sqrt{N_WN_V\sigma_W^2\sigma_V^2}
+
N_WN_V\mu_W\mu_V
.
\end{equation}

where $\rho_{WV}$ is the correlation defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence). Using the independence mentioned before, we know that $\mu_W = \mu_X\mu_Z$ and $\mu_V = \mu_Y\mu_Z$. We also know that,

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\sigma_W^2 &= \mathbb{E}[X^2]\mathbb{E}[Z^2] - \mathbb{E}[X]^2\mathbb{E}[Z]^2 \\[0.25cm]
&= (\sigma_X^2 + \mu_X^2)(\sigma_Z^2 + \mu_Z^2) - \mu_X^2\mu_Z^2
\end{split}
\end{equation}
with a similar result for $\sigma_V^2$. Therefore, all we need to determine is $\rho_{WV}$. Using the definition,
\begin{equation}
\rho_{WV}
=
\frac{\mathbb{E}[W\cdot V] - \mathbb{E}[W]\mathbb{E}[V]}{\sigma_W\sigma_V}
.
\end{equation}

Now, all quantities but $\mathbb{E}[W\cdot V]$ have been determined already. Observe then,
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[W\cdot V] = \mathbb{E}[X\cdot Z\cdot Y\cdot Z] = \mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y]\mathbb{E}[Z^2] = \mu_X\mu_Y(\sigma_Z^2 + \mu_Z^2)
.
\end{equation}
From here we have obtained all the required quantities in terms of the given means and variances.

I believe this result is correct but I am having difficulty reproducing the result numerically. Did I make any mistakes?

Thanks in advance!